# Pandas dataframe sum if

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have the following df:

```
d = {'col1': [0.1, 0.2, 1.2]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to sum up every value smaller than 1.
As I get as a result 0.3 in this case. How to do it ideally?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dataframe.loc[dataframe['col1'] < 1, 'col1'].sum()
```

Or:

```
dataframe.mask(dataframe['col1'] > 1).sum()['col1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the higher than 1 values and sum:

```
dataframe.where(dataframe['col1'].lt(1))['col1'].sum()
```